# ModelState.isValid is false because Id model property is clashing with passed parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to MVC still and am having a hard time figuring out how best to work around this issue.

I have a modified version of an auto-scaffolded `"Create" (GET)` action that takes an optional parameter (a default value for a drop-down list).  It then submits it's form to the `"Create" (HTTPPost)` action.

```
public ActionResult Create(string id = null)
{ 
    //use id to pick a default item in a drop down list.
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Registration registration)
{ 
    //this method doesn't care one iota what was passed to the GET method
    // but registration.id is invalid because it's trying to set it to the value that was passed to the get method.  If id in the get method is not passed, then everything is fine
}
```

The problem is, if a value was passed to the GET create action, then `ModelState.isValid` is false on the `POST create` action because it's trying to stuff the value that was passed to the GET action into the primary key (Id) field of the model in the POST action (which should be omitted since it's auto-generated.

I know I could just change the primary key column name to something other than Id, but I don't have control over the database and am trying to figure out another remedy to this issue.

If I try renaming the parameter on the GET action from 'id' to something else then I have to change the links from  `CREATE/paramValue`  to `CREATE/?paramName=paramValue` and I'd rather not do that.  (though I will if it's the only easy way).

Is there a way to make it so the POST action ignores the values passed to the GET action?

Comment: Do you have one method in controller for both POST and GET, or separate two methods?

Comment: @pkmiec - Two separate methods.  I didn't even suspect that the HttpPost one would know about the parameter passed to the Get one.  Updated the question to show the method signatures

Comment: Hm.. and why do you pass the parameter for GET Create action by route param? It seems to me that you can work around this issue by using TempData, which will not occupy place in route param, and won't be model binded in POST action.

Comment: Or maybe you could elaborate on "a default value for one of the database form elements". Where do you get those default values in code? Are those values visible for the user in view? Or you rather set them in application code before saving entity?

Comment: Is Registration a domain model or a view model?  Ideally, you should not be passing domain models to your views, you should be creating a view model that only holds the necessary properties and supporting items (drop down list,etc).  By using this method, you a) may not need the id property in the form or b) can simply map the domain model property to something like RegistrationId

Comment: @pkmiec - I'm still learning MVC and am not familiar with TempData. I'll update the question with more information.

Comment: @Tommy - Registration is an Entity Framework/Database Model.  The Methods were auto-generated by the scaffolding options and I don't think I even changed the httpPost one at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is parameterize the Create method of your controller with the ID of the type of object it is supposed to create.

While there is no hard and fast convention on parameter names in ASP.NET MVC, I think most people expect the parameter called `id` to refer to the object that is being dealt with, rather than an attribute of it.

With this in mind, my suggestion to you would be to do the following:

1. Rename the parameter in the GET version of the Create method to something suitable like typeId or whatever, so the signature then looks like `public ActionResult Create(string typeId = null)`
2. Add a custom route to the `MvcApplication`, which will let you have the nicely formatted `/Create/typeId`, rather than forcing to to have `/Create?typeId=value`

You can do this by adding the following lines of code before you default route:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "CreateGet",
    url: "Controller/Create/{typeId}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Controller",
        action = "Create",
        typeId = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

The default route looks something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Site",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

I think this will solve your problem, though make sure the custom route I am suggesting comes before the default route.

**Update:**

You have a Get method and a Post method.

The Get method (probably) creates a view model object and sends that to the view, which renders it. Alternatively, your view could have various inputs hard-coded in the HTML or injected in via an AJAX call. Regardless of how they got there, your rendered view that goes out to the web browser looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
<form>
<input id="Input1" ... />
<select id="Select1" ... />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is a vastly simplified structure of the HTML that goes out.

The IDs of the inputs match the names of the properties within the view model object that will be created when this page is posted back, i.e., an instance of the `Registration` class.

On the way back (to the Post method), a model binder takes the values from the request (query string parameters, form values, etc.) and binds them back into the model object that is given to the Post method.

In your case, most likely what was happening was that there was a mismatch between what `id` meant in the Get method (and in the rendered view) and what `id` meant in the `Registration` object given to Post method.

The reason for the mismatch was that the `Registration.Id` property name was dictated by the database and `Create(string id)` was being dictated by the default route, but they are actually different things, so should be named differently.

That left your need to have a clean URL of the /Create/id form, which is easily done by a custom route.

Now if you really wanted to exclude a parameter from the model binding logic, then you would go with the other answer which used an attribute on the `Registration` parameter of the Post method to explicitly tell the `DefaultModelBinder` to exclude that parameter from the binding logic.

Once you'd done that, the property it would have bound to would have retained its default value given to it by the CLR after instantiation and running constructors.

ASP.NET MVC also supports custom model binders which can alter the model binding logic significantly, if required, though that doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: The `Controller` in the custom route should be changed to the name of the controller that contains your Create methods, rather than being left as `Controller`.

Comment: +1, This works.  I didn't know you could have multiple formulas for routes, but I am still early on in my MVC knowledge.  This answer is a little more involved than the one by @mipe34, are there any nuances that I should know about in chooses which to implment?

Comment: I have added an explanation regarding the use of both my approach as well as the one taken by @mipe34. Please mark as accepted answer if this has clarified your question :)

Answer (score 3):

Try use `BindAttribute`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "RegistrationId")]Registration registration)
{ 

}
```

It will omit the `RegistrationId` POSTed with form when binding to model...

Comment: +1, This works, but I'd still like to make it so the parameter I pass to the GET create method only stays in the scope of that method (I don't even want it passed on to the view).  I'm not sure though how it all works behind the scene though and if it's event possible

Comment: What kind of `HtmlHelper` methods are you using to display that entity (or create the form)?

Comment: I'm using the parameter to determine which element to use as the default in a `SelectList`, I create the SelectList in the controller,  then pass the SelectList on to the View and use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper with said `SelectList`.

Comment: I still do not get could you please post to your question the code of `[HttpGet]` create method and some crucial portion of your view?